# Batch file not write variable in ftp, mput

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have this script, but it does not work.
My script can not find the location for  `%APPDATA%\*`

```
 open IP
 USER
 PASS
 bin
 mput %APPDATA%\*
 bye
```

I need `mput C:\Users\Gio\AppData\Roaming\*` so it looks like it doesn't load the variable.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your FTP script with a batch file first and echo the commands to a new file. That file can be read by the ftp command.

```
@echo off

echo open IP > cmds.ftp
echo  USER >> cmds.ftp
echo  PASS >> cmds.ftp
echo  bin >> cmds.ftp
echo  mput %APPDATA%\* >> cmds.ftp
echo  bye >> cmds.ftp

ftp < cmds.ftp
```

Notice the file that gets created is called cmds.ftp. A single > indicates to create a new file, a double >> appends the echo-ed output to the file.